# Making my drop downs sticky?

Tags: php, html, forms, sticky

I am very new to PHP (and programming in general) and I am trying to make my form fields sticky so each time the user clicks submit their choice stays selected in the drop down. The code is properly changing the font, color, etc but it keeps going back to the value at the top of the drop down.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Example</title></head>
<body>

<form name="FontFamilyForm" method="post">

  <select name="fontFamily">
    <option value="serif">Serif</option>
    <option value="sans-serif">Sans-serif</option>
    <option value="fantasy">Fantasy</option>
    <option value="monospace">Monospace</option>

  </select>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<form name="FontSizeForm" method="post">

  <select name="fontSize">
    <option value="100">Normal</option>
    <option value="60">Tiny</option>
    <option value="80">Small</option>
    <option value="120">Medium</option>
    <option value="150">Large</option>
    <option value="200">Extra Large</option>

  </select>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>


<form name="BackgroundColorForm" method="post">

  <select name="backgroundColor">
    <option value="#ffffff">Normal</option>
    <option name='beetch' value="#dddddd">Light Grey</option>
    <option value="#aaaaaa">Medium Grey</option>
    <option value="#888888">Grey</option>
    <option value="#333333">Dark Grey</option>
    <option value="#000000">Black</option>

  </select>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>



<?php

    if (isset($_POST['fontFamily']))
    {
        $fontFamilyVar = $_POST['fontFamily'];

    }

    if (isset($_POST['fontSize']))
    {
      $fontSizeVar = $_POST['fontSize'];  
    }

    if (isset($_POST['backgroundColor']))
    {
      $backgroundColor = $_POST['backgroundColor'];  
    }





?>
    <style type="text/css">

        body { 
           line-height:1.5;
           width:640px;
           margin:0 auto;
           font-family: <?echo $fontFamilyVar?>;
           font-size: <?echo $fontSizeVar?>%;
           background-color: <?echo $backgroundColor?>;
           color: #dddddd;
       }
       label {width:12em;float:left;}
    </style>

    <p>Test string blah blah blah blah blah</p>


</body>

<html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to update your code as per below:

```
<select name="fontFamily">
    <option <?php if($fontFamilyVar=="serif")      echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="serif">Serif</option>
    <option <?php if($fontFamilyVar=="Sans-serif") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="sans-serif">Sans-serif</option>
    <option <?php if($fontFamilyVar=="Fantasy")    echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="fantasy">Fantasy</option>
    <option <?php if($fontFamilyVar=="Monospace")  echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="monospace">Monospace</option>
</select>
```

Also put your below PHP code at the top of the page, not a bottom:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['fontFamily']))
    {
        $fontFamilyVar = $_POST['fontFamily'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['fontSize']))
    {
      $fontSizeVar = $_POST['fontSize'];  
    }
    if (isset($_POST['backgroundColor']))
    {
      $backgroundColor = $_POST['backgroundColor'];  
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because after the post back, your selection is getting lost. You can change the dropdown's selected value using Sessions.

```
<select name="fontFamily"> 
    <option value="serif"<?=$_SESSION['fontFamily'] == "Serif" ? ' selected="selected"' : ''?>>Serif</option> 
    <option value="fantasy"<?=$_SESSION['fontFamily'] == "Fantasy" ? ' selected="selected"' : ''?>>Fantasy</option> 
</select>
```

Using Sessions even if the user refreshes the page (F5) the values in the dropdown will not change to the default ones.

Don't forget to Start the Sessions and assign the values to them on post back.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your post! I will definitely look more into sessions.

Answer (score 0):

The primary way I do this is by simply sticking the previously selected option at the top of the list with the "selected" tag. This works fine for lists where the order is not particular.

Another way to do this would be to make an array of your option values, then loop through the array and compare the previously selected value to each option in the array.

```
$option_value = "two";
$array = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four');
$array_count = count($array);

echo "<select name=\"numbers\">";

for ($i=0; $i<$array_count; $i++){
    echo "<option value=\"$array[$i]\"";

    if ($array[$i] == $option_value){
        echo " selected";
    }

    echo ">$array[$i]</option>"
}

echo "</select>";
```

If you're building an option list for something like the minutes in an hour, you can do the same thing, only you don't have to declare an array ahead of time, you just use the $i value of the loop to build from.